# Buddypress Welcome Email

Tags: buddypress

How do I edit the buddypress welcome email received by users and admin. I have tried numerous plugins but none work. I am not a developer so am pretty lost.

Comment: Third party plugins and themes are off topic, they are better asked about at their developers' support routes.

Answer (score 1):

For the activation email, you can use the filter hook in buddypress\bp-members\bp-members-functions.php

```
$message = apply_filters( 'bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message', $message,    $user_id, $activate_url );
```

For example, try this in your theme/functions.php

```
function gavin_welcome_message( $message, $user_id, $activate_url ) {
    $message = 'Gavin says something here... ' . $message;
    return $message; 
}
add_filter('bp_core_signup_send_validation_email_message', 'gavin_welcome_message', 15, 3);
```